# $f$ is totally differentiable, show that $F:x\mapsto\langle f(x),v\rangle$ is totally differentiable.

Tags: analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}^p$ is a totally differentiable function. Show that $F:x\mapsto\langle f(x),v\rangle$ is also a total differentiable function.

Let $a\in\mathbb{R^n}$. I want to prove that

$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|F(a+h)-F(a)-A(h)|}{|h|}=0$

Filling in $F$ gives

$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|\langle f(a+h),v\rangle-\langle f(a),v\rangle-A(h)|}{|h|}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|\langle f(a+h)-f(a),v\rangle-A(h)|}{|h|}$

Let $A(h) = \langle A_{f}(h),v\rangle$, where $A_f(h)$ is the total differential of f in $a$. $A$ is linear because $A_f$ and the inner product is linear.

$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|\langle f(a+h)-f(a),v\rangle-A(h)|}{|h|}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|\langle f(a+h)-f(a)-A_f(h),v\rangle|}{|h|}$

I'm stuck trying to prove this limit is equal to $0$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives

$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|\langle f(a+h)-f(a)-A_f(h),v\rangle|}{|h|}\leq\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{| f(a+h)-f(a)-A_f(h)|}{|h|}|v|=0*|v|=0$

We see that $F$ is totally differentiable independent of our choice for $v$. Thank you Giuseppe for your tip.

Comment: No problem. Note that you can have any matrix $m\times p$ matrix $M$ multiplying $f$, and you would get the same result. Linear maps are to this theory what constants are to usual derivatives of one variable.